# Foreach genera pases duplicados al insertar

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy trabajando en Wordpress trayendo datos desde una API que me han proporcionado.
La traída de datos es correcta, por motivos del proyecto tengo que traer datos desde la API y luego guardar estos en tablas personalizadas de wordpress, una tabla con varios campos para ser exacto.

Todo funciona correctamente, traigo los datos, los guardo en un array y simplemente lo recorro e inserto con `$wpdb->insert()`.

```
foreach ($json['Elementos'] as $key=> $value){
$wpdb->insert("publicaciones",
    array(
        'idpublicacion' => $value['IdPublicacion'],
    ),
);
```

}

Tan sencillo como eso.

Ahora mi consulta, pasa que si digamos la API me retorna 15 elementos para guardar, llega todo correcto, es mas, verifico el array y los 15 vienen correctos, pero al momento de recorrer y guardar duplica un par de filas y no las inserta. Al final de 15 elementos solo guardo 13 y verifico con `$wpdb->print_error();` y efectivamente los duplica, dejo el código que me retorna que si inserta pero "genera duplicados".

```
16145 <----ID QUE IMPRIMO PARA VERIFICAR QUE SI VIENE EL DATO CORRECTO
Error en la base de datos de WordPress: []
INSERT INTO `publicaciones` (`idpublicacion`, `titulo`) VALUES ('16145', 'Efficacy of a self-management education programme on patients with type 2 diabetes in primary care: A randomised controlled trial.')

13778 <----ID QUE IMPRIMO PARA VERIFICAR QUE SI VIENE EL DATO CORRECTO
Error en la base de datos de WordPress: []
INSERT INTO `publicaciones` (`idpublicacion`, `titulo`) VALUES ('16145', 'Efficacy of a self-management education programme on patients with type 2 diabetes in primary care: A randomised controlled trial.')
```

Como ven, el ID (idpublicacion) es el mismo en los 2 pases, pero el que está como actual es correcto. Al pasar esto pues el que tiene valor 13778 ya no es insertado.

Agradezco cualquier consejo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Esas dos filas que no se insertan es probablemente porque violan alguna restricción en la base de datos. Por ejemplo, si hay otro registro idéntico que ya existe y la tabla tiene una restricción  `UNIQUE` las filas que violen esa restricción no se insertarán.

Comment: Hola y gracias, si es por eso, pero la pregunta es por que los repite cuando en el array no están repetidos.

Ese es el problema, al traer todo, no hay elementos repetidos pero al pasar por el foreach si aparecen algunos.

Comment: No creo que los repita sin estarlo realmente. Lo puedes comprobar haciendo un `print_r($json['Elementos']);`, ahí te mostrará todo lo que hay dentro del array que estás recorriendo.